# Tag external git repository after Azure DevOps release

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, devops

I am quite new to Azure DevOps and here is my situation.

Build Pipeline (BitBucket connection)

1. dotnet build
2. dotnet pack
3. publish artifacts

Release Pipeline (Manually Triggered)

1. dotnet push
2. How to ?????

Question: How to tag the bitbucket repo after the release?

I have looked for answers and only tagging solutions i found were for TFS/VSTS repos but can't find much info on tagging bitbucket repo from release pipeline.

I do have a plan B if i don'd find a simpler/elegant way of doing this.

**Plan B:**

Build Pipeline (define git repo url and credentials in variables)

1. git checkout via powershell using repo url and credentials from variables
2. dotnet pack
3. publish artifacts

Release Pipeline

1. dotnet push
2. git tag & git push tag from powershell script using repo url and
   credentials from variables

Comment: I was in the same boat, and I ended up transferring the authoritative Git repo to Azure DevOps so I can use the 3rd party [vsts-git-release-tag](https://github.com/jabbera/vsts-git-release-tag) extension. There doesn't appear to be a better way at the moment that doesn't involve some custom scripting, API calls, or web hook.